# Dice - Opposite and Adjacent Faces

Tags: dice

I'm trying to teach my son Dice problems and I'm not able to understand it myself. I would be very thankful if anyone can help.

So, in the example problem, how does he assume that 3 is also adjacent. 3 or 1 could be adjacent correct?

http://www.indiabix.com/verbal-reasoning/dice/introduction

Rule No. 1:
Two opposite faces cannot be adjacent to one another.

Example:
Two different positions of a dice are shown below. Which number will appear on the face opposite to the face with number 4?

[image]

Solution:
Faces with four numbers 6, 2, 5 and 3 are adjacent of to the face with No. 4.
Hence the faces with no. 6, 2, 5 and 3 cannot be opposite to the face with no. 4.

Therefore the remaining face with no.1 will be the opposite of the face with no. 4.

Comment: It's badly written "adjacent" means the number values are adjacent.  So 1 can not be opposite 2.  2 can not be opposite 3.  3 can not be opposite 4.  Etc.  In the picture we see that 2,5,6 are not opposite 4.  So that leaves 1 or 3.  But 3 is one less than 4 so it can not be opposite the 4.  That leaves only one.